# what is AllowEmptyStrings in Required Data Annotation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have Added `Required` Data Annotation to my Data Model Class.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required", AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am wondering what does it do actually,

because results are some what confusing to me.

Input to textbox : Only few Spaces(`"     "`) passes the model Validation ,where as

Input To Textbox: empty (`""`) ,fails the model validation.

But earlier i thought  `""` is `empty string`,so this case should be one to pass the model validation.

Why this unexpected behaviour?Where did i get thing wrong?

Comment: `""` translates to `null` (nothing is provided) so `ModelState` will be invalid, but `"   "` means you are proving a value (although its just empty spaces)

Answer (score 0):

It will check any non-null string values. Because the string type is inherently `nullable`, empty strings passed to the ModelBinder are read as `null`